# Do we need readlock while using function pointer & static variable?

Tags: c, linux, concurrency, mutex

do we need a read lock for reading an integer other than if the variable is less than memalign and during some caching situation ?

Comment: I don't understand this. What exactly is your question? Also, I don't see the variables above being `static`. Also, if in case you need a global variable which is accessed via different threads, declare it `volatile`

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: @noMAD: The variables `x` and `y` have static storage duration.  And `volatile` is neither necessary nor sufficient for safe concurrent access.

Comment: I agree, I think we should assume x, y are static variable(does it make a difference anyways ?) also i think we should assume t() called using pthread_create...  btw, its a quote (copy-pasted) a chapter from pc-lint document so I am trying to figure out too if there is any relation between function pointer (who's function just reads no writes ) and static variable and multiple threads accessing those functions/vars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The analyser assumes that because the address of `f1()` has been taken, it could be called through that function pointer from any context.  If, for example, you have one thread updating `x`:

```
lock xlock;
update x;
unlock xlock;
```

and another thread calls `f1()` simultaneously through the function pointer, the access to `f1()` in that second thread won't be protected by the lock.  It could therefore see a partial update of `x`, or see the update incorrectly ordered with respect to other updates.

The reason why the function pointer matters is that if the address of `f1()` is never taken, then the analyser can determine exactly where the function is called from.  When the address has been taken, it has to assume the worst case.

Comment: +1 "partial update of x" - are u referring to integer reads not being atomic if memalignment is less than sizeof(int) or caching ?

Comment: @purpletech: The requirements for a read to be atomic are platform-specific - and anyway the analyser doesn't know if the single `int` needs to be consistent on its own or if its part of a larger data structure that needs to be internally consistent.  Note that the pthreads memory model doesn't guarantee that you can access even a correctly aligned `int` as an atomic operation - it requires synchronisation primitives between racing reads and writes.

Answer (score 1):

From the text you quoted (emphasis mine):

> If a function has had its address taken, then **we presume that we do
>   not know the context of every call made upon that function**.

Because lint cannot determine every context that a call to `f1` could be made in, it assumes that it could be called in any context, including those in which accessing `x` results in some data race.

Reasonably, you probably won't hit anything dire by returning `x`. But it's a probability, and the whole point of using lint is to reduce uncertainty with respect to how your code functions with unexpected inputs.